# Is there is a way to import a full project in my python project without changing imports of the other project?

Tags: python, import

I make a new folder and place project1 with all its files in this folder1

**folder1  ---> include project1**

and another folder to include project2

**folder2 ---> include project2**

Now, I want to import folder2 in my project to include all files of project2.
The problem is now I must change all imports of project2 to **folder2.oldImports**

How I can import a full project without having this happen?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

"import" searches for packages in the "sys.path" list. So in theory you could do:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('folder2')

import oldImport
```

However, this feels kind of hacky (e.g. you don't understand imports, when you are not reading the main file), so I would just change the imports:

```
import folder2.oldImports as oldImports
```